# Why am I getting this "AppLifecycleEvent" crash?

Tags: crash, library

macOS has been greeting me with weird crashes caused by scripts from "~Library/Application Scripts":

[image: macOS Crash]

The first line in the stack trace leads to this:

> 6H4HRTU5E3.com.avast.passwords.PasswordsHelperApp

I discovered that this is a "script" from the "~/Library/Application Scripts" folder. However, it looks like this is a ghost folder - there are only subfolders in there with no files whatsoever:

[image: Empty Subfolders]

What is this folder and is it safe to erase it completely if it's empty anyways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of your crashes is Avast AV software. Make sure you've installed a version that is compatible with your OS, or uninstall it completely (this may require running an uninstaller - contact Avast for details).

Application Scripts are, as the name suggests, scripts that are specific to a given application. The OS creates a folder for each application installed, regardless of whether it has any scripts or not.

From what I can read in your picture, the paths given are to /Library/Application **Support**, not **Scripts**, which is a different thing altogether.

That is the root level /Library folder, not the one in the user domain. That is where apps may install component files that are essential to their running.

I'd recommend just uninstalling Avast instead.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking at the user-level "Library", not the root one.